# How do I use the Azure AD Authorization Code Flow?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, azure-ad-graph-api, claims-based-identity

I am building an ASP.NET (v4.8) Web application that will be hosted as an Azure App Service, but for now we are on localhost.

I am configured for Azure AD successfully and I am receiving an authorization code because I configured my app service to send the access token.  The app registration has ONLY `User.Read` (delegated) permissions.

[image: App Registration Settings - Access Tokens]

In my `Startup.cs` file, I've configured `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications` so that I am receiving the `access code` in `AuthorizationCodeReceived`.  Here is the code:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType );
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        authority = aadInstance + tenantId;
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions  {
            ClientId = clientId, Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                TokenResponseReceived = (tr) => { return Task.FromResult(0); }, 
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = (code) => {
                    // you are here! what's next?
                    access_code = code.Code;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenReceived = (token) => 
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = (context) => { return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0); }
            }
        });
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
    }
```

> My objective is to call this graph endpoint as the current user to get their JobTitle and > Department from Azure AD.  Here is the resource: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

I was following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), but it was not clear what to do with the provided `access_code`.  Please help me understand.

1. Is this `access_code` a bearer token? can I use it directly to call the graph API?
2. Do I have to use it to call the /token endpoint to get a bearer token?
3. Do I have to use it to call the /authorize endpoint to get a bearer token?
4. I am making direct HTTP requests now, should I use MSAL or Graph SDK?

I think I am trying to accomplish this step:

[image]

This is the code I am currently working on, and it returns `HTTP CODE 400` (Bad Request):

```
private void GetOtherProfileData()
{
    var cId = Startup.clientId;
    var tenantId = Startup.tenantId;
    var scope = Startup.scope;
    // scope: https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read
    var code = Startup.access_code;
    var redir = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Startup.redirectUri);
    var req_url = $@"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token?client_id={cId}&scope={scope}
                        &code={code}&redirect_uri={redir}&grant_type=authorization_code
                        &code_verifier=ThisIsntRandomButItNeedsToBe43CharactersLong";
    var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(req_url);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentLength = 0;
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var resp = req.GetResponse();
    var str = resp.GetResponseStream();
    var json = new StreamReader(str).ReadToEnd();
    Trace.TraceInformation(json);
    /// this should return bearer token and then we go call the /me endpoint... 
///right?
}
```

Any code samples or pointers to recent documentation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this access_code a bearer token? can I use it directly to call the graph API?

> > No, code and Access_token are different. You will need a access_token to call Graph API.

Do I have to use it to call the /token endpoint to get a bearer token?

> > Yes, you'll need code to call token endpoint to get the bearer token.

Do I have to use it to call the /authorize endpoint to get a bearer token?

> > You will get the code after calling authorize endpoint. You need to pass grant_type=code to get the code in response.

I am making direct HTTP requests now, should I use MSAL or Graph SDK?

> > You'll need to call Graph API after you get the access_token. Along with the token it also needs proper dedicated and application User permissions from Azure side.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good sample here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect

I was trying to do this without a `client secret`, that was a mistake.

This is how I implemented it =>

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) => {
    // you are here!
    IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
    AuthenticationResult result = await clientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(new[] { "User.Read" }, context.Code)
                        .WithSpaAuthorizationCode() //Request an authcode for the front end
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                    access_code = result.AccessToken;
                    // this is the bearer token.
                },
```

This is what is inside the implementation of `BuildConfidentialClientApplication`:

```
clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Startup.clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(Startup.secret)
            .WithRedirectUri(Startup.redirectUri)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri(Startup.authority))
            .Build();
```